# Get complerte related model details with model id: Django REST

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have two models User and Item.
The model Item is

```
class Item
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='items',null=True)
```

A user will have more than one item. The user serializer is

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
model = User
    fields = ('id','username','items')
```

So that i can access the list of all the items of a user. But here the field items returns only the 'item id', I need the whole item model related to a user. How can i get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For customization list of related objects (`items`) you can use [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). I prefer write another serializer for `Item` objects and use it for serializing in this method.

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_items(self, obj):
        return ItemSerializer(obj.items, many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','username','items')
```